# Windows Sockets send stringstream

Tags: c++, sockets, stringstream

I’m trying to send a stringstream through a TCP socket connection. The problem is that windows sockets only takes a const char data array. What would be the best and most efficient way to send a stringstream data type using sockets?

```
char *szMessage="Hello World";
send(Socket,szMessage,strlen(szMessage),0);
```

I’m willing to learn a different sockets library if windows native sockets library is not sufficient for this job. Also I’ve also just started using Boost C++ libraries for threading and their sockets library looks a little more advanced but I’m unsure if it supports sending stringstream’s.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`stringstream` provides functions to retrieve a `const char*`, see the [documetation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/):

```
std::stringstream ss( ... );

ss.str().c_str(); // now the const char *

send(Socket,ss.str().c_str(),ss.str().length(),0);
```

Comment: I think you mean that `stringstream` provides a function to retrieve a `std::string` which can be used to get a `const char *`? :)

Comment: Yes, of course. All I wanted to say, is that it's not too complicated to obtain a C string out of a `stringstream`.

Comment: You should call `stringstream::str()` once and store the result in a local variable, not call it twice inline, which will allocate and free two temporary `std::string` instances instead.

Comment: Again, I wanted to demonstrate the easy retrieval of a C string from a `stringstream`. I know, that there is room for optimization, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and not confuse with other classes, which are, in this context, not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a socket API is to send bytes. The byte datatype in C++ is `char`.

To send a more complex datatype across a socket, you need a protocol. Windows provides (DCE) RPC. Many people use SOAP. There are lots of others.

A `stringsrteam` contains characters. If you control both ends of the connection, the difference between characters and bytes may not be important to you. If you do not, it can be very important, since the two ends can disagree on the interpretation unless you are careful to make sure that both use the same character encoding.